# Prevent vue cli from deleting all files in dist

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, github, vue-cli-3

I am developing vue project and syncing dist folder with git. This worked well while using webpack. However, I have moved to @vue/cli --- `using vue create myProject` instead of `vue init webpack myProj`.

The issue is that every time i run `npm run build`, it deletes dist folder and recreates it -- all .git and other files gone.

How do I prevent new build from deleting required files in dist folder and only update the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to answer by Yom S. the documentation [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build) does provide way to keep older dist.

However, the you can't use `--no-clean` like `npm build --no-clean`. To use no clean mode from terminal you need to write following command instead

```
./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service --no-clean
```

**Update**

Instead you can also add --no-clean in package.json

Comment: Actually I think you can do that. You just need to pass the parameter a little differently, given npm script `build: vue-cli-service build` you can pass additional flags after `--` so in CLI you'd call `npm run build -- --no-clean` and npm would pass the params after `--` to the actual script command.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have your own mechanism for cleaning up the old resources, [`vue-cli-service build`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build) comes with this option called `--no-clean` to instruct the compiler not to remove the "dist" directory before building the project.

So, add the switch/option to the `build` script on **package.json**:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --no-clean"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you use Yarn, you can pass additional argument(s) right after the script name. So there's no need to make any change to the script. To run it:

```sh
yarn build --no-clean
```

Comment: tried npm run build --no-clean --- old files removed (created test.txt in dist folder to test)

Comment: It won't work like this. You have to provide --no-clean to `vue-cli-service` so best way is to put this to package.json as `"build": "vue-cli-service build --no-clean",` and then you can just run `npm run build` @mayank1513

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, @KoviNET. I updated the answer to include that.